# How can get the text of a div tag using only javascript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

I tried this but showing "undefined".

```
function test() {
var t = document.getElementById('superman').value;
alert(t); }
```

Is there any way to get the value using simple Javascript no jQuery Please!

Answer (score 218, accepted):

You'll probably want to try `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Given `innerHTML` will return DOM content as a `String` and not exclusively the "text" in the `div`. It's fine if you know that your `div` contains only text but not suitable if every use case. For those cases, you'll probably have to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

For example, considering the following markup:

```
<div id="test">
  Some <span class="foo">sample</span> text.
</div>
```

You'll get the following result:

```
var node = document.getElementById('test'),

htmlContent = node.innerHTML,
// htmlContent = "Some <span class="foo">sample</span> text."

textContent = node.textContent;
// textContent = "Some sample text."
```

See MDN for more details:

- [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent)
- [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:element.innerHTML)

Comment: `.textContent` isn't supported in IE8 and lower, which makes it somewhat hard to use.

Comment: True. Indead, `innerHTML` don't returns only the text content as requested in the question. I'd implement a solution based on `.textContent` feature detection with a fallback for <IE9

Comment: Although an older question, _.textContent_ is the more appropriate answer for today's world.

Answer (score 13):

Because `textContent` is not supported in IE8 and older, here is a workaround:

```
var node = document.getElementById('test'),
var text  = node.textContent || node.innerText;
alert(text);
```

`innerText` does work in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `innerHTML`(then parse text from HTML) or use `innerText`.

```
let textContentWithHTMLTags = document.querySelector('div').innerHTML; 
let textContent = document.querySelector('div').innerText;

console.log(textContentWithHTMLTags, textContent);
```

`innerHTML` and `innerText` is supported by all browser(except FireFox < 44) including [IE6](https://caniuse.com/#search=innerText).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you dont need to call `document.getElementById()` function to get access to your `div`.

You can use this `object` directly by `id`:

```
text = test.textContent || test.innerText;
alert(text);
```