# In WebDriver, is it possible to get the content of the tag which is not visible?

Tags: java, html, webdriver

I have an html tag which is not visible on screen (isDisplayed returns false) but i want to get the value of it. For eg:

```
<div class="qgwy">Gift No.3726</div>
```

I want to extract the value "Gift No.3726". I tried this code and it prints nothing:

```
WebElement gwy = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".qgwy"));
System.out.println(gwy.getText());
```

After careful comparisons, I realized that, the getText() method only works for elements' tag which are visible (or not hidden) on screen. So, I was wondering if it's possible to extract that data without asking my developers to modify the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, its possible:

Q: Why is it not possible to interact with hidden elements?
A: Since a user cannot read text in a hidden element, WebDriver will not allow access to it as well.

However, it is possible to use Javascript execution abilities to call getText directly from the element:

```
WebElement element = ...;
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].getText();", element);
```

from Selenium FAQ:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Why_is_it_not_possible_to_interact_with_hidden_elements?

Comment: Thanks Alex for the reply. Can you help me to point out where I am doing it wrong as I am getting exception: "arguments[0].getText is not a function"

WebElement elm = browser.findElement(By.cssSelector(".desktopmode"));
   
String hiddenvalue = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) browser).executeScript("return arguments[0].getText();", elm);
   
System.out.println(hiddenvalue);

Comment: Seems like element was not found. Check that elm variable is not null

Comment: It's not null. Tried with other visible object where it prints the value of the html tag using webdriver getText() method. However, javascriptexecutor always complains by exception (getText() is not a function).

Comment: replace getText() with .innerHTML http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370204/how-can-get-the-text-of-a-div-tag-using-only-javascript-no-jquery

Comment: Yes, innerHTML works. Thanks Alex for helping out till the end.