# Changing where to put text

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a very basic if statement and it reads like this:

```
var p1 = document.getElementById('p1').value;
var p2 = document.getElementById('p2').value;

if(p1==p2){
    document.write("P1=P2");
} else {
    document.write("P1 Does Not Equal P2")
};
```

Followed by the following HTML

```
<p id="p1">2</p>
<p id="p2">4</p>
```

I just want to be able to identify the if the value within `p1` is greater or less than the value of `p2`. Eventually this will have bigger consequences than just `document.write` but at this time the if statement does not recognize the content in between the `<p></p>`.

Comment: I assume your problem is `p1` and `p2` dont have the correct values. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370204

Answer (score 0):

p tags do not have a value. You can get the [innerHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) and compare that instead:

```
var p1 = document.getElementById('p1').innerHtml;
var p2 = document.getElementById('p2').innerHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

Paragraph tags don't have a value, so you would need to use innerHTML.

```
var p1 = document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML;
var p2 = document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML;

if(p1==p2){
    console.log("P1=P2");
} else {
    console.log("P1 Does Not Equal P2")
};
```

However, that doesn't solve the 2nd part of the problem, since you mention that eventually you will need to know > or <, also.  To make that happen, you would can change your tags to something else (a div?) or convert the resulting values to numbers.

```
var p1 = document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML;
var p2 = document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML;

var v1 = Number(p1);
var v2 = Number(p2)

console.log(p1);
console.log(p2);
console.log(v1);
console.log(v2);

if(v1==v2){
    console.log("P1=P2");
} else {
    console.log("P1 Does Not Equal P2")
};
```