# Call alert function when div text equals 10

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a game that when you get 10 strikes, there should be a alert telling you Game Over. The alert is not working. The StrikeNumber ID is the ID of the DIV that once it is 10, the alert should happen. This is pure Java Script.

```
function GameOver(){
if (document.getElementById('StrikeNumber').text === "10"){
    alert("gameOVER");
   }
}


HTML DIVS

<div id="StrikeNumber">
0
</div>
<div id="ScoreNumber">
0
</div>
```

Comment: show your html code also !!!

Comment: added the divs!

Comment: Have you bind the div's click event to GameOver?

Comment: The divs have no Click event, they are just text that start at 0.

Comment: Try the code in my answer might help you

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JQuery then you can use the .change() method and write logic inside that method.

`$("#StrikeNumber").change(function(){
    alert('strike changed');
});`

Comment: I'm using pure java script.

Comment: @Graham here's a pure JavaScript translation of the above: `document.getElementById('#StrikeNumber').onchange = function() { alert('strike changed') };`

Answer (score 1):

The div element dose not have a text property. You have to use the textContent property.

```
if (document.getElementById('StrikeNumber').textContent === "10"){
    alert("gameOVER");
   }
```

[get text from doc tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370204/how-can-get-the-text-of-a-div-tag-using-only-javascript-no-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `text` , use `innerHTML` or `textContent` . Your html look like having whitespace so using `trim()` is a better solution . You need to learn `==` & `===` difference at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

```
function GameOver(){
if (document.getElementById('StrikeNumber').innerHTML.trim() == "10"){
     alert("gameOVER");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code might help you

```js
(function() {

    var x = document.getElementById("StrikeNumber").innerHTML;

    if (x == 10) {
      alert("Game Over !!!");
    }

  }

)();
```

```html
<div id="StrikeNumber">
  10
</div>
<div id="ScoreNumber">
  0
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use innerHTML to get the content of a div.

```
function GameOver(){
    if (document.getElementById('StrikeNumber').innerHTML === "10"){
    alert("gameOVER");
   }
}
```

You also need to make sure that the GameOver() method is called after every div content update.

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work. Thanks for response though.

Comment: How would I go about making sure the method is called after every time the div is updated?

Comment: You call it right after the action that you use to update the Dev. you also need to make sure that the div contains "10" without any whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.

```
setInterval(function(){
  if(div.textContent === '10') {alert('strike')}
}, 50);
```

Comment: that broke my game xD