# Alert returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, alert

I am trying to have my alert show up with the time that my timer shows.

```js
function Stopwatch(elem) {
  var time = 0;
  var offset;
  var interval;

  function update() {
    if (this.isOn) {
    time += delta();
  }

  elem.textContent = timeFormatter(time);
}

function delta() {
  var now = Date.now();
  var timePassed = now - offset;

  offset = now;

  return timePassed;
}

function timeFormatter(time) {
  time = new Date(time);

  var minutes = time.getMinutes().toString();
  var seconds = time.getSeconds().toString();
  var milliseconds = time.getMilliseconds().toString();

  if (minutes.length < 2) {
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }

  if (seconds.length < 2) {
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  }

  while (milliseconds.length < 3) {
    milliseconds = '0' + milliseconds;
  }

  return minutes + ' : ' + seconds + ' . ' + milliseconds;
  }

  this.start = function() {
    interval = setInterval(update.bind(this), 10);
    offset = Date.now();
    this.isOn = true;
  };

  this.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
   this.isOn = false;
  };

  this.reset = function() {
    time = 0;
    update();
  };

  this.isOn = false;
  }

  var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
var toggleBtn = document.getElementById('toggle');
var resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');

var watch = new Stopwatch(timer);

function start() {
  toggleBtn.textContent = 'Stop';
  watch.start();
}

function stop() {
  toggleBtn.textContent = 'Start';
  watch.stop();
}

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  watch.isOn ? stop() : start();
});

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  watch.reset();
});

function alertSystem(){
  var timer = document.getElementById('timer')
  alert(timer);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="timer">00 : 00 . 000</h1>

<div>
  <button class=button id="toggle">Start</button>
  <button class=button id="reset">Reset</button>
  <button onclick='alertSystem()'>get number</button>
</div>
```

It's a lot of code, but it is mostly to get the timer working. The last function called `alertSystem()` is on the bottom and is the one that triggers the alert call. For me the alert shows up as `[object HTMLHeadingElement]` or as `undefined`. The former comes up when I have `alert(timer);` but if I do `alert(timer.value);` or `alert(timer.length);` I get the latter.

Does anyone know how I can just get the value of the timer in the alert?

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can get the text of a div tag using only javascript (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370204/how-can-get-the-text-of-a-div-tag-using-only-javascript-no-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the timer's value, you should do something like:

```
document.querySelector('#timer').innerHTML
```

Otherwise , document.getElementById returns a full element as a js object.

Comment: This goes inside the alert right? It worked! Thank you so much.