# Hide some text from a div content

Tags: javascript, html, webserver, plc

How to take a text from a div and cut the information that I don't need?

Example:
I take a information about a time from a web server on a PLC, and this server returns this `#T15_05` where it has minutes and seconds, is that a way to create a function to cut and transform this time for something like this `15:05`?

```
<!-- AWP_In_Variable Name='"webdata".Takt' -->

<div class="takt">
    <p>TAKT</p>
    <div class="Takt" id="takt">:="webdata".Takt:</div>
</div>
```

This `<!-- AWP_In_Variable Name='"webdata".Takt' -->` is how I get the information from the PLC web server.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what template language you are using? It would help in providing you with a solution.

Comment: I'm using JS and Jquery to take and update the information in HTML

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can get the text of a div tag using only javascript (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370204/how-can-get-the-text-of-a-div-tag-using-only-javascript-no-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is change the div contents you could place a script at the bottom of your html page, right before the closing body tag.

```
<body>

<!-- AWP_In_Variable Name='"webdata".Takt' -->

<div class="takt">
    <p>TAKT</p>
    <div class="Takt" id="takt">:="webdata".Takt:</div>
</div>

<script>
    var webData = document.getElementById('takt');
    var content = webData.innerText;

    webData.innerText = content.replace('#T', '').replace('_', ':');
</script>
</body>
```

Going this route would expect that the information coming from your PLC is always formatted as #T{hour}_{minute}. If your format may be different then a different approach would need to be taken. This specific code would transform `#T15_05` to be `15:05`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the time returned from the server is in the #id 'takt':

```
const targetNode = document.getElementById('takt');
const time = targetNode.innerText;
targetNode.innerText = time.replace('#T', '').replace('_', ':');
```