# How to get data output from HTML in JS?

Tags: javascript

How can I get the '123' value from the following code? I thought the snippet should work but I instead get email :....

```
<div id="home">
    <div class="name" my-data="123">Email: test@gmail.com</div> 
</div>
```

---

```
var element = document.querySelector('.element');
var dataAttribute = element.getAttribute('my-data');

console.log(dataAttribute);
```

Comment: if you change the HTML to `class="email"` (as that's what the JS is looking for) [then it works](https://jsbin.com/hiloriqazu/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: Thanks, and how can I get the email string instead? @VLAZ

Comment: By *not* getting the attribute value. [How to get the pure text without HTML element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6743912) | [How can get the text of a div tag using only javascript (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10370204)

Comment: Isn't this just a typo? The code works after using the correct class name.

Answer (score 0):

You try to use `querySelector` with `.element`, that class doens't exist instead you need to use `.name`

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.name');
var dataAttribute = element.getAttribute('my-data');

console.log(dataAttribute);
```

```html
<div id="home">
    <div class="name" my-data="123">Email: test@gmail.com</div> 
</div>
```

---

Just for your knowledge you could use `data-attribute` like this:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.name');
var dataAttribute = element.getAttribute('data-email');

console.log(dataAttribute);
```

```html
<div id="home">
    <div class="name" data-email="123">Email: test@gmail.com</div> 
</div>
```

Reference:

- [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)
- [QuerySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector?retiredLocale=en)

---

For pick text of div email use `textContent` like:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.name');
var dataAttribute = element.getAttribute('my-data');

console.log(dataAttribute, element.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="home">
    <div class="name" my-data="123">Email: test@gmail.com</div> 
</div>
```

Reference:

- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: Yes it's true (i didn't know), i just prefer use `data-attribute` for more readeble code

Comment: Why? resolve the problem? Yes, it's just another way no?

Comment: I twisted the answer by giving priority to the class problem

Comment: thanks, any idea how I can get the text content of the div (Email) with JS?

Comment: I update answer @theoseo

Comment: Thanks you are a life saver? Can you also help me how to assign the following cookie function to 'test@gmail.com'?................................var element = document.querySelector('.name');
var dataAttribute = element.getAttribute('my-data');

console.log( element.textContent);

Comment: You want to store this email into cookie?

Comment: I want to add a cookie with the value 'test@gmail.com' with a 2 months expiration @Simone Rossaini

Comment: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

When using a custom attribute, make sure to write "data-", and then the rest of the attribute name. Doing that, you can easily access the data from javascript.

```
<div class="name" data-something="123">Email: test@gmail.com</div>
```

And for the js:

```
let element = document.querySelector('.name')
let dataAttribute = element.dataset.something
```

Comment: thanks, any idea how I can get the text content of the div (Email) with JS?

Comment: `let text = element.textContent`

Comment: Thanks, do. you know how I can add a cookie to that email which expires in 2 months ?   I think the code should be something like this but I do not how to add the value of the email: function myemail () {
    var expiryDate = new Date();
  expiryDate.setMonth(expiryDate.getMonth() + 2);
    document.cookie = cookieName + '=y; expires=' + expiryDate.toGMTString