# document.getElementById returns HTMLDivElement {}

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have the following code in my HTML file:

```
    <div id="calc-parent">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id="calc-display-val">0</div>
    </div>
```

I need to get the value of calc-display-val, so I have the following JavaScript code:

```
let calcDisplayVal = document.getElementById("calc-display-val")

function pressOne() {
console.log(calcDisplayVal)
}
```

But instead of 0, I get "HTMLDivElement {}"

How can I get the value of calc-display-val?

Comment: Well, how about `let calcDisplayVal = document.getElementById("calc-display-val").innerHTML`?

Comment: You are logging the HTML element itself. What you probably want is to return the text content for it (eg: innerHTML, innerText and textContent). See above comment for the example, that should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can get the text of a div tag using only javascript (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370204/how-can-get-the-text-of-a-div-tag-using-only-javascript-no-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.innerHTML` for this :

```js
let calcDisplayVal = document.getElementById("calc-display-val")

function pressOne() {
  console.log(calcDisplayVal.innerHTML)
}

pressOne()
```

```html
<div id="calc-parent">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id="calc-display-val">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: arguably the OP only needs the `textContent`

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the print of your div's content:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("calc-display-val").innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="calc-parent">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column" id="calc-display-val">0</div>
        </div>
</div>
```