# console.log the buttons insides <button> 'text i want in console' </button>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to `log` my button's inner text when user clicks on the button, this is what I tried:

```
    function AComponent()  {
        const logMywords = (e) => {
            console.log(e.target.value) 
    }
    
    return (
      <button onClick={logMyWords(e)}>
           'my words!' 
      </button>
      )
    }
```

Comment: You want to get the buttons text not value

Comment: correct. the words 'my words!'.
the words that a user would see on their screen.

Comment: it's innerHTML...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can get the text of a div tag using only javascript (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370204/how-can-get-the-text-of-a-div-tag-using-only-javascript-no-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

To get your button's inner text:

```
function AComponent() {
  const logMyWords = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
  }

  return (
    <button name="myButton" onClick={logMyWords}>
      'my words!'
    </button>
  );
}
```